type alias dependent name in a derived class: invalid use of incomplete type?
I want to understand the usage of the type alias in templated derived class as shown in the simple example,below. I got an error message: "invalid use of incomplete type.
My problem is: I have a templated derived class whose template parameter is the base class and I need to access to the type of the base class.
The simple example below doesn't complile with the error message at line 21: "invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct B2’".
Can you explain why case 1 doesn't complain and why case 2 doesn't compile?
Is there a way to get around?
struct A {};

/* Case 1: this implementation compiles well */
struct B1: A {
  using type = typename B1::A;
};


/* Case 2: this implementation doesn't compile */
template<class U>
struct B2: U {
  using type = typename B2::U;
};


int main() {
  // Case 1
  B1 b1;  // OK

  // Case 2:
  B2<A> b2;  // error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct  B2<A>’
}


It helps a lot if you note the programming language as one of the question tags.

The question is related to C++.

Please always tag c++, not just c++XX alone. Also please don't add line numbers to code, we want to be able to copy-paste it.

"Is there a way to get around?..." Just replace it with using type = U; 

typename B2::U will result in recursion.

The error isn't very descriptive, but it's correct. Your first working case isn't really comparable, which is why it serves to confuse you. Let's alter it a bit.
struct A {};

using U = A;

struct B1: U {
  using type = typename B1::U;
};

Which now produces the same complaint from GCC, B1 is incomplete. Why? It's because it assumes that you meant to define U in B1, but it can't know about it since the alias isn't what is known as a "complete class context".
B1 doesn't contain any U either, and neither does its base. The base class is A and so any injected class name is going to be A. U is just an alias to A, about which A knows nothing about.
That is pretty much comparable to the template case.
As for the use case you describe, it doesn't really explain why you want to go through B2 at all. If U is a template parameter already, then you can name it just fine.
using type = U;


The error message (from GCC) appears to be wrong, B2 doesn't need to be complete for typename B2::?? to work. This compiles:
template<class U>
struct B2 : U
{
    using T = int;
    using type = typename B2<U>::T;
};

Your second class still shouldn't compile, but for a different reason. Template parameters are not members of their class template, you can't refer to them using ::.
You can, however, as mentioned in other answers, just do using type = T;.

"B2 doesn't need to be complete...." It does actually require it to be complete. See old post

@user12002570 Are you saying that typedefs are not instantiated before the first use? Okay, but it works everywhere, not only in typedefs: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3noqYPGP7


why case 2 doesn't compile?

Because when you wrote typename B2::U, we're actually looking for a member named U inside the instantiated type B2<U>. But since there is no "member" named U in B2<U>, we get the mentioned error.

Is there a way to get around?...

Yes, there are two ways to solve this.
Solution 1
Just replace it with using type = U; 
Demo
Solution 2
Second option is to make what you're looking for a member. Since we can't make U a member as it will shadow the template parameter with same name U, we can create alias with some other name T as shown below:
template<class U>
struct B2: U {
  using T = U;   
  using type = typename B2::T; 
};

